# Frostwire not opening

Tags: 12.04, java, openjdk

I have just donwloaded the application FrostWire. I was trying to open it, but it just won't open. The icon does it's flashing, and then it goes back to the normal background, no windows from that app at all. I checked the syslogs, and there isn't anything that I could find that had to do with it not opening. It's not appearing on System monitor either. I do have OpenJDK 7 as it is required to run the program. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the source of my problem-
I went into terminal to try to open it, and it turns out I just downloaded the wrong version of OpenJDK.